# Is It Possible to Run Out of Log Sequence Numbers?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I’ve been wondering about the algorithm for generating log sequence
numbers for transaction log records, and I’m concerned that with a
high enough workload it might be possible to run out of log sequence
numbers.

What happens in that case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the following answer from a post written by [Paul Randal](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/94938/paul-s-randal).

[Is It Possible to Run Out of Log Sequence Numbers?](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/it-possible-run-out-log-sequence-numbers)

Paul writes:

> There’s no need to worry because for all practical purposes it isn’t
>   possible to run out of log sequence numbers. As a bit of background, a
>   log sequence number is a three-part number used to uniquely identify a
>   transaction log record—constructed from the sequence number of the
>   virtual log file (VLF) containing the log record, the log block number
>   within the virtual log file, and the log record number within the log
>   block.
>
> This isn’t really important, but what is important is that the VLF
>   sequence number is a 64-bit number. Whenever a VLF is reused in the
>   transaction log, the VLF sequence is increased by 1. So let’s do a
>   little math.
>
> Imagine a transaction log with 65,536 VLFs, each 1/4MB in size (not a
>   nonsensical situation, depending on how your transaction log is being
>   managed—for more details on this and on transaction log internals, see
>   [“Importance of proper transaction log size
>   management."](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/importance-of-proper-transaction-log-size-management/).
>   Each time the log is completely used and wraps around to the start,
>   the VLF sequence number will increase by 65,536, which is 2 to the
>   power of 16 (2^16).
>
> A 64-bit number can support 2^64 values. To be able to exhaust the
>   2^64 possible VLF sequence numbers, our example transaction log would
>   have to wrap 2^64 / 2^16 = 2^48 times. That’s a lot of log wrapping.
>   But how much transaction log does that equate to?
>
> Our example log is 65,536 x 1/4MB in size, which is 16GB. To wrap that
>   log 2^48 times, you’d need to generate 2^48 x 16GB of transaction log,
>   which equates to four billion petabytes (a petabyte = 1024 terabytes)
>   of transaction log—quite an undertaking!
>
> Even being able to write that log out to a solid-state drive (SSD)
>   capable of a sustained 600MBps, it would take four billion petabytes /
>   600 megabytes = approximately 240 million years to generate four
>   billion petabytes of transaction log. As you can clearly see, no one’s
>   in any danger of running out of log sequence numbers!